# Is $1 ÷ \frac {1}{0}$ a valid operation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a simple yet confusing that I was discussing with my teacher.

For $1 ÷  \frac {1}{0}$, we would know that we cannot do the operation with the undefined number. Yet, for $1 \times  \frac {0}{1}$, it works.

The original question is to find the restrictions for $\frac {2x^2 + 6x}{x-3} ÷ \frac {10x^3}{x^2-9}$.

I insisted the restriction is x $\neq$ 3, 0 as we can always flip a division to make it multiplication. While my teacher says x $\neq$ 3, 0, **-3** as she says the original equation won't work otherwise.

Comment: x=-3 is a removable singularity and removing the singularity makes it a different function

Comment: Thank you, this explanation is simple and straightforward!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We always need to refer to the original expression, for example

$$\frac{x}{\frac1x}$$

is not defined for $x=0$ though for $x\neq 0$ it is equal to $x^2$.

Then in this specific case your teacher is completely right indeed to define

$$\frac{\frac {2x^2 + 6x}{x-3} }{ \frac {10x^3}{x^2-9}}$$

we need

- $x\neq \pm 3$
- $x\neq 0$

though

$$\frac{\frac {2x^2 + 6x}{x-3} }{ \frac {10x^3}{x^2-9}}=\frac{(2x^2 + 6x)(x+3)}{10x^3}$$

and the RHS only requires $x\neq 0$.

Comment: So my teacher is correct then?

Comment: @Kevin Yes of course! I've added something more specific on that.

Comment: For the unless part, it is predetermined that x $\neq$ 3, -3 so only requires x$\neq$ 0? If I understand correctly.

Comment: @Kevin The last expressions are equivalent only for $x\neq -3,3,0$.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you!